# Unable to pass object in server

Tags: angularjs, struts2

I am trying to pass an object to server but it is not accepting on server 
my angularjs code is

```
 $scope.sharePost = function () {
        console.log('Share post');
        console.log($scope.sharePostData);
        console.log($scope.sharePostData.reSentBy.id);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "share-post",
            dataType: 'json',
            //data: {senderId: $scope.sharePostData.reSentBy.id},
              data: {pmu: $scope.sharePostData},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).then(function successCallback(rs, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(rs);
            console.log(rs.data.st + "  " + rs.data.msg);
         }, function errorCallback(data, status, header, config) {
            alert("Opps unable to connect to server");
        }
        );
```

At Chrome  under network form data is showing

```
{"pmu":{"adddate":"2018-02-23T12:26:11","atomByAuthor":{"fname":"a","id":2337,"lname":"a"},"atomByReceivedBy":{"fname":"a","id":2337,"lname":"aa"},"atomBySentBy":{"fname":"a","id":2337,"lname":"a"},"id":1782,"postMessages":{"message":"hiiiiiiiiiii","messageid":1776},"reReceivedBy":{"id":"2337"},"reSentBy":{"id":"2337"},"reMessage":"sdfasdfasdfasdf","reMessageVisibility":"Private"}}
```

I want to assing this data in pmu object in server.

Where I am wrong?

I want to send entire object where fileds may variable

Comment: did you get the message "Opps unable to connect to server" ?

Comment: Yes I got  it    Opps unable to connect to server

Comment: Please check the responseHeaders and paste it here :)

Comment: Please check here https://pastebin.com/kaC7ubTt   error changed to  function errorCallback(data, status, header, config) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.data.st + "  " + data.data.msg);

            alert("Opps unable to connect to server");
        }

Comment: @Oyeme is data passing way is correct

Comment: Have you tried passing data like data: $scope.sharePostData

Comment: Try to post an array instead of an object.

Comment: Try to convert the object to a json string for example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: @SudhirOjha yes tried not working

Comment: I have an object pmu under that all properties are there i want to assing properties of pmu